# Positioning Elements on Edge of Container

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hopefully this is better explained with the picture I mocked up here:

[image]

I have a full-width, 100vh area that has a `.container` that's 100% width / 1200px max-width and 100vh as well (centered of course.). Inside of this container I'll have 3 elements (the red X's).

How can I get the center point of these elements to literally stick to the edges of the container? My end goal is to have them seemingly floating, but then as the screen width shrinks and the `.container` width starts to collapse that the items follow that edge and look to be just peaking into the screen.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/bmoneruiux/full/WvQePY)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue. Transform change the flow of the original objects size. So while my elements were scaled down, their original bounding boxes weren't. #themoreyouknow

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if the irems belong to the container, with `position:fixed` and the proper `top` / `left` values, they should stick even if you move the container or resize the screen. If not, you could also use a function that whenever the container is resized the elements positions are changed proportionally.